# INSERT statement for one column to populate each row

Tags: sql, insert

I have a table called books that I just altered to have a column called yearPUB. I'm trying to populate each row with a year but it's not working. This is the INSERT statement I'm using.

```
INSERT INTO books (yearPub)
    VALUES (2002),
           (2006),
           (1999),
           (2005),
           (2003),
           (2001),
           (1998),
           (1968),
           (2009),
           (1988),
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure that is your intent? If you altered an existing table to add a column, if you insert you will get new rows, not update existing ones.

Comment: What is your table's structure? Do you want to update your data, or insert new row? Which DB do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert them one at a time, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO books (yearPub) VALUES (2002);
INSERT INTO books (yearPub) VALUES (2006);
```

Alternatively, you could insert using a subquery with a select statement.  The syntax may differ depending on what database you are using.  For example, you could follow an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) and write something like:

```
INSERT INTO books (yearPub)
SELECT yearNumber FROM othertablename;
```